# how to get Styles from existing word document by using Novacode.Docx?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk, novacode-docx

This is the Example code using OpenXML SDK 2.5

```
     void AddStylesPart()
    {
        StyleDefinitionsPart styleDefinitionsPart = mainPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;
        styleDefinitionsPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<StyleDefinitionsPart>();
        Styles styles1 = new Styles();
        styles1.Save(styleDefinitionsPart);


        if (styleDefinitionsPart != null)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordTemplate = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"..\AT\Docs\FPMaster-4DEV.docx", false))
            {
                foreach (var templateStyle in wordTemplate.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.Styles)
                {
                    styleDefinitionsPart.Styles.Append(templateStyle.CloneNode(true));
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Here an existing document is taken using **WordprocessingDocument** class **finally Cloned all the styles present in existing document**, 
similarly I want to do it using Novacode.Docx DLL. **How to get styles used in existing document** using Novacode.Docx DLL? kindly please help.

Comment: scenario: I have a word Document called **Dev**, they used different styles in it. 
I'm going to generate new word document, where I need to add styles which are present in **Dev** . These must be done using Docx dll

Comment: Your question is unclear.  When you say "this is the code for OpenXML", do you mean docx4j or novacode?  When you say "Docx DLL", what is that?

Comment: Hi @JasonPlutext The Code which I've posted is written using OpenXML SDK 2.5. similarly I want to achieve it using Novacode [Docx.codeplex](https://docx.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I also Have another Question, is it possible to have Content Controls using   novacode [Docx](https://docx.codeplex.com) @JasonPlutext Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know nothing about novacode, sorry.  It is possible with docx4j.NET, but since this question appears to have nothing to do with docx4j, I'm removing the tag.

Comment: Ok Thanks :) @JasonPlutext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative solution, I hope this will help

Using Novacode.Docx DLL we can easily clone the styles used in original document.
It can be done by creating [template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-Word-document-as-a-template-1a20aa19-5ca4-4b40-bdf2-57a2168c1e89?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) of the original document.

once If it is done. apply the template in your project.

```
document.ApplyTemplate(@"..\TemplateFileName.dotx", false);
```

Now we can able to use all styles present in original document.